# RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED - When will it be triggered?

Tags: android

I need my app to start a service. I have read many questions including this one (see Answer 1): [Trying to start a service on boot on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2784441/trying-to-start-a-service-on-boot-on-android)

I am pretty happy with Answer 1 but have a question regarding the `RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED`. Will this only be triggered after the boot, or will it also be triggered (or emulated) when the user installs or first-time starts the app, or do I have to make sure for myself that the service is started the first time via another method, as the device did not technically boot up and technically should not send the `BOOT_COMPLETED` message.

Comment: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html#RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED

Comment: Thanks Nilesh, I already read this, but it does not clarify my question if I need a fallback mechanism for manually starting it if the device did not boot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED` is a broadcast message that can **only** by sent by the System. Additionally, as seen from this [documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/broadcast-exceptions), it is a Broadcast that's only sent **once**.

Therefore, your Broadcast Receiver for `RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED` **will not** trigger upon the first install or the first run of your app. Your Android Device will only broadcast this message once, and that's when it completes it's first boot.

So if you wish to ensure your Service is running, it's not enough to rely on the Boot Complete Broadcast. After all, if the system decides to kill your Service for whatever reason, such as needing memory, then your Service is dead until the next boot... which isn't what you want.

Honestly, the `RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED` broadcast is mainly used as a supplementary method for starting a Service rather than it's primary method.

Comment: Thank you very much for this detailed answer. I will do it as a supplementary method and use something else as primary method

Comment: If you can avoid listening for boot entirely, then avoid it. The reason why boot is so slow on android is because every app wants to be started on boot.